# How to set a Timeout in java for Android Development?

Tags: java, android, timeout

I'm working on an app for Android 4.0 and later using Java.

I want to set a timeout method in java that starts automatically and runs a method after 5 seconds.

Please tell me how to do that with explanation.

I researched a lot about it on the Internet, but I couldn't get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
   public void run() {
      // Your method code here
   }
};
timer.schedule(task, 5000);
```